# How is this "number square" problem done with a modulus operator?

Tags: java, loops, modulo

I have come across a very familiar problem doing some exercises and for the life of me cannot figure it out using the intended method -- the modulus `%` operator -- that accepts `(int min, int max)` parameters as beginning and end limits.

It is to print the following with a call of `numberSquare(1, 5)`:

```
12345
23451
34512
45123
51234
```

I have gotten it to work by essentially creating a manual tracker, though I know this is not the correct approach:

```java
private static void numberSquare(int min, int max)
{   
    int difference = max - min;
    // outside loop
    for(int row = min; row <= max; row++)
    {
        // inside loop
        for(int col = row; col <= row + difference; col++)
        {   
            // is in bounds
            if(col <= max)
                System.out.print(col);
            // not in bounds
            else
                System.out.print(col - difference - 1);
        } // next line
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And my other approach using the operator had the inner loop looking like this:

```java
// is in bounds
if(col <= max)
    System.out.print(col);
// not in bounds
else
    System.out.print(col % max + min);
```

Which gives me an output of:

```
|12345|                  |12345|
|23452|                  |23451|
|34523|    instead of    |34512|
|45234|                  |45123|
|52345|                  |51234|
```

I am really struggling to see how I can do this with the modulus `%` operator and would love any help/suggestions.

**Edit for additional information**

I got another version to work, but this one also does not have the `%` operator...

```java
private static void numberSquare(int min, int max)
{
    // track outside rows
    for(int row = min ; row <= max; row++)
    {
       // track inside columns and the print value
       for(int col = min, value = row; 
               col <= max; col++, value++)
       {
           // reset if the value is too high
           value = (value > max) ? min : value;
           System.out.print(value);
       } 
       // next line
       System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

Comment: 'the modulus % operator': there is no modulus operator in Java. % is the remainder operator. Not the same thing.

Comment: Why did my professor call it that?

Comment: Similar to how there is a Boolean value in C with the name bool, there is a Modulus operator in Java referred to as either the Remainder or the Modulo. https://codeparttime.com/modulus-operator-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your *integer* is `abcd` where each letter is a digit. You can do left cyclic shift by first separating `bcd` and `a`

```
bcd = abcd % 1000
a = abcd / 1000 (integer division)
```

Then, to construct the left cyclic shift from `bcd` and `a`

```
bcda = bcd * 10 + a
```

In Java, this is how I would implement it

```
void numSquare(int min, int max) {
    long number = 0;
    long div = 1;
    // construct the integer, e.g., 12345, and the corresponding power of tens
    for (long i = max; i >= min; --i) {
        number += i * div;
        div *= 10;
    }
    div /= 10;
    
    // left cyclic shifting the integer and printing
    int nShifts = max - min + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nShifts; ++i) {
        System.out.println(number);
        number = (number % div) * 10 + (number / div);
    }
}
```

If you want to print digit-by-digit and must use `%`, the trick is to subtract the column by `min` to shift the range to `[0, max-min]`, use `%` to relapse once reaching the maximum, then re-add `min` to turn it back to normal range, like so

```
void numSquare(int min, int max) {
    int len = max - min + 1;
    for (int row = min; row <= max; row++) {
        for (int col = row; col < row + len; col++) {
            System.out.print((col - min) % len + min);
        }
        System.out.println(); // break line when we do a new row
    }
}
```

I would advised against this approach if possible because of its many calls to `System.out.print`, which can add up over time.

Comment: would this be more realistic than resetting each time it hit the max number? Though my version is more intuitive for me (go figure right?) I'd love to know which would be more "future-proof" if that's even the right term for it here. Basically, is there a better algorithm or is it just preference?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the value as `(row + col - 2) % max + 1`